# How to create an admin route and another private route for registered users with a normal route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have used this code  as the private route, but I want a another separate route only for admins. How can I change the code?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Private = ({ component: Component,
    auth:{loading, isAuthenticted},
     ...rest 
    }) => (
    <Route 
    {...rest}   
    render={props =>
        !isAuthenticted && loading ?
        (<Redirect to='/signin'/>
        ):(
        <Component {...props}/>)
    } 
        /> );

        Private.propTypes={      
           auth:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
          }
          
          const mapStateToProps=state=>({
            auth:state.auth
          })

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Private);
```

Comment: you can add a role value in your data , which may be sent from the server ,it can have value admin/user and then same like above you can create another component called adminRoute which will check for the value isAdmin/role along with isAuthenticated

Comment: yes I have the role, the problem is how to make the component of adminRoute

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Spinner from '../layouts/Spinner';

const Admin = ({ component: Component,
    auth:{loading, isAuthenticated,user},
     ...rest 
    }) => (
    <Route 
    {...rest}   
    render={props =>
      loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : isAuthenticated ? (

        (user.userRole=='Admin')?

        <Component {...props} />:( <Redirect to="/index" />)
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/signin" />
      )
    }
        /> );

        Admin.propTypes={      
           auth:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
          }
          
          const mapStateToProps=state=>({
            auth:state.auth
          })

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Admin);
```

I added user Role field which is already in my state.